# NG-Hide Volunteer Search

Tags: civivolunteer

I only have 12 items per volunteer project so I was hoping to hide the Search as it's pointless. I looks like there's code to control that but I can't find a way to turn it on or it's not functioning properly.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 4):

appended &hideSearch=1 and that took care of it. Modified the css for the cart to width 100%.